# Backbone.js, following router link doesn't render new view

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

When I click link on page, the URL in browser changes, but the view doesn't change. When I refresh the page the view renders just fine.

My itemView.js goes something like this:

```
var ItemView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'tr',
    className: 'single-item',
    template: _.template('<td><%= name %></td><td><%= phoneNumber %></td><td><a href="/#people/<%= id %>"class="details">Click for details</a></td>'),


    render: function(){

        this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.attributes));
        this.$el.attr('data-itemid', this.model.id);

        return this.$el;
    }

});
```

router.js

```
var UserRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
    initialize: function () {
        this.mainView = new MainView();
        this.listView = new ListView();
        $('.wrap').append(this.mainView.render());
    },

    routes: {
        "people/:id": "showPerson"
    },

    loadView: function(view){
        if( this.view ){
            this.view.remove();
        };
        this.view = view;
        this.mainView.$el.html(this.view.render());
    },

    showPerson: function(id){
        var self = this;
        this.listView.collection.on('sync', function () {
            var myModel = this.get(id);
            self.loadView(new SingleView({model: myModel}));
        });
    }

});
```

And in main.js

```
var router = new UserRouter;
Backbone.history.start();
```

As you can see I use router as an app entry point. I just don't understand - do I have to handle links clicks or the router is supposed to do it?

Generated links look like this:

```
<a href="/#people/5" class="details">Click for details</a>
```

Comment: Does it fail to call `self.loadView`?

Comment: @fibono No, if I go to http://localhost:3000/#people/5 it renders the single view just fine.

Comment: So would you say it's not syncing properly?

Comment: I'm not sure. I'm just learning backbone here. And I couldn't find a good example for how people do this - you click `<a href="/#something/1"`, the URL changes and the view rerenders. I have my render code in a router, but do I have to duplicate it in a view or what?

Comment: I haven't worked in Backbone.js for a while (but I noticed no one's been responding yet to this post). I've always set it up so that in your view, you have: `initialize: function() { this.listenTo(this.model, 'sync', this.render); //or a collection }`, so the view renders automatically whenever the model or collection "syncs"

Comment: Yes, I'm listening to a sync in my listView.js

Comment: Where in your code is the collection being synced with the server? I'm curious because you say that the callback inside the `this.listView.collection.on()` is being called (thus `self.loadView` is called).

Comment: What is `SingleView` ..?!